# How do I stop an item being sortable in a jquery UI sortable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list, some items with a class "sort":

```
<ul id="items">
   <li class="sort">ITEM 1 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
   <li class="sort">ITEM 2 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
   <li class="sort">ITEM 3 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
   <li class="sort">ITEM 4 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
   <li>ITEM 5</li>
   <li>ITEM 6</li>
   <li>ITEM 7</li>
   <li>ITEM 8</li>
</ul>
```

I have then initialised the list as sortable for all items with the class "sort".

```
$("#items").sortable({
    items: "li.sort"
});
```

This works fine, however, I want to be able to fix the position of the sortable items so that they can no longer be dragged. I've started by adding a button to remove the class "sort" from the list item. This is the code for the button:

```
$("#items").on("click", ".fix-position", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();        
    $(this).parent().removeClass("sort");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

This does prevent the other items from using it as a drop target, but the item can still be dragged itself. See JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3Js5u/1/

I have also tried to refresh the list:

```
$("#items").sortable("refresh");
```

but that does not seem to work.

Only other option I can think of is to destroy the sortable list and recreate it like this:

```
$("#items").sortable( "destroy" );
$("#items").sortable({
    items: "li.sort"
});
```

JS FIDDLE for that option: http://jsfiddle.net/3Js5u/3/. Not sure if that's the best way to go though. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking for, already exists in jquery UI documentation. Check the first example in the link.
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items

Comment: @nightgaunt I've got the answer now. Hadn't thought to combine both items and cancel. Your link does not show the 2 combined either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the opposite and use [`cancel`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) option instead.

*HTML:*

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>ITEM 1 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
    <li>ITEM 2 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
    <li>ITEM 3 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
    <li>ITEM 4 <a href="#" class="fix-position">Fix Position</a></li>
    <li class="static">ITEM 5</li>
    <li class="static">ITEM 6</li>
    <li class="static">ITEM 7</li>
    <li class="static">ITEM 8</li>
</ul>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$("#items").sortable({
    cancel: ".static"
});

$("#items").on("click", ".fix-position", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("static").end().remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Js5u/2/

Comment: Thanks. But looking at your demo it does seem to mean that I can use any list item as a drop target which I don't want.

Comment: @AndrewPolland Still I don't see the problem of combining both: http://jsfiddle.net/3Js5u/4/.